# What pressure do objects at exhaust of pipes feel from flowing fluid? Dynamic or Total?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, fluid, water-pressure

Let's imagine that we have one fluid source separated somewhere in two pipes of R1 and R2, and we put one object at exhaust of R1 pipe and one more object at exhaust of R2 pipe (R1 > R2). Let's also assume that **total pressures of these two fluid are the same** since they are coming from the same source and they are just split in two pipes with different radius.

Now, my question is which object will experience more force from fluid? In my opinion, the object at exhaust of narrower pipe (R2) will face more force than another object with R1 pipe(broader).

Since total pressure of fluids is the same, I think they only feel dynamic pressure of fluids and this is why R2 object experiences more force as dynamic pressure of R2 object is higher due to higher velocity.

Do you also think that they feel only dynamic pressure?

If yes, why don't they feel static pressure?

If no, why do they feel different forces whereas total pressures are the same?

Comment: Let's imagine a situation like this: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/54645/10902

Comment: @SolarMike No, let's not. They are not the same. That question was about object inside the pipe, where static pressure of fluid cancels out itself by applying on every side of the object. This question is about an object inside atmosphere and being hit by fluid in motion. Different cases.

Comment: the total pressure at the beginning of the pipes may be the same, but the smaller pipe will experience more head loss.  This can be calculated via any of several on-line flow calculators.